# How to add a newline in a double quoted string

Tags: ruby

I have have some code like this:

```
system("notify-send -i 
  #{Dir.pwd}/#{file} 
  #{parsed_songlist["song"][0]['title']} 
  #{parsed_songlist["song"][0]['artist'].concat("#{parsed_songlist["song"][0]['albumtitle']}")} )
```

The albumtitle follows the artist name. How can I add a newline between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `"\n"` before the string to be added.

Comment: I change to this `send=parsed_songlist["song"][0]['artist']+"\n"+parsed_songlist["song"][0]['albumtitle']` and put it in the command. It can work but the shell will notice that `sh: 2 (the albumtitle): not found`. So weird

Comment: That's because you are using `system()`. It is as if you are typing the lines in the shell. Once you hit enter, you are entering a different command. `bash` is telling you it doesn't understand your second line. Try escaping the "\n" by preceding it with another "\".

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
"\'#{parsed_songlist['song'][0]['title']}\' 
\'#{parsed_songlist['song'][0]['artist']}\n#{parsed_songlist['song'][0]['albumtitle']}\'"
```

The problem in your command is if your title/artist/albumtile contain multi-words like `hello hi` then in command it will appear as `notify-send -i /home/username/file hello hi ...`

So you could see how that multi-words 'title' converted as two argumenst for `notify-send`.
To tackle such problem use `\'` as I used above.

However, '\n' is enough for adding a newline in a double qouted string.

Here, is what I get when I used above

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`.

```ruby
system("notify-send -i 
  #{Dir.pwd}/#{file} 
  #{parsed_songlist["song"][0]['title']} 
  #{ [
       parsed_songlist["song"][0]['artist'],
       parsed_songlist["song"][0]['albumtitle']
     ].join("\n") }"
)
```

Comment: It is a string class, so I guess it do not have the `join` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think `\n` is enough :

```
"#{parsed_songlist["song"][0]['artist']".concat("\n#{parsed_songlist["song"][0]['albumtitle']")
```